# How do I restrict page access on user properties

Tags: .net-core, blazor, blazor-client-side

I have a blazor page I need to restrict access to by age. I am using hosted webassembly. I would like to use [Authorize] attribute but I can not figure out how to make it work on a calculation from date of birth. I'm storing the date of birth in DateTimeOffset format.

Comment: Is the DoB a property of the ApplicationUser class?

Comment: Yes  "public DateTimeOffset DoB { get; set; }"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly you need to make the Dob a claim. I am not sure if you should use `JwtClaimTypes.BirthDate` as your datetime format is not the same as what is expected here.

```
 public class CustomUserClaimsPrincipalFactory
         : UserClaimsPrincipalFactory<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>
    {
        public CustomUserClaimsPrincipalFactory(
            UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager,
            RoleManager<IdentityRole> roleManager,
            IOptions<IdentityOptions> optionsAccessor)
            : base(userManager, roleManager, optionsAccessor)
        { }

        public override async Task<ClaimsPrincipal> CreateAsync(ApplicationUser user)
        {
            ClaimsPrincipal principal = await base.CreateAsync(user);
            var identity = (ClaimsIdentity)principal.Identity;

            var claims = new List<Claim>
            {
                new Claim(JwtClaimTypes.BirthDate, JsonSerializer.Serialize(user.DoB))
            };
...
            identity.AddClaims(claims);
            return principal;
        }
    }
```

To use this add this line to startup.cs on the server code

```
services.AddDefaultIdentity<ApplicationUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
               .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
               .AddClaimsPrincipalFactory<CustomUserClaimsPrincipalFactory>();
```

You also need to make sure the claim gets added to the JWT so the client can see it.

```
 services.AddIdentityServer()
                .AddApiAuthorization<ApplicationUser, ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
                {
                    const string OpenId = "openid";

                    options.IdentityResources[OpenId].UserClaims.Add(JwtClaimTypes.BirthDate);
                    options.ApiResources.Single().UserClaims.Add(JwtClaimTypes.BirthDate);
                });
```

You then have to set up a Policy in `Program.cs` for the client

```
  builder.Services.AddSingleton<IAuthorizationHandler, MinimumAgeHandler>();
  builder.Services.AddAuthorizationCore(options => options.AddPolicy("AtLeast18", policy => policy.Requirements.Add(new MinimumAgeRequirement(18)));
```

Then you can use the [Authorize] attribute on your page.

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization
@attribute [Authorize(Policy="AtLeast18")]
@page "/adults"

<h3>Adults Only</h3>
```

Policy Classes:

```
  public class MinimumAgeRequirement : IAuthorizationRequirement
    {
        public int MinimumAge { get; }

        public MinimumAgeRequirement(int minimumAge)
        {
            MinimumAge = minimumAge;
        }
    }

   public class MinimumAgeHandler : AuthorizationHandler<MinimumAgeRequirement>
    {
        public MinimumAgeHandler(IDateTimeBroker dateTimeBroker)
        {
            DateTimeBroker = dateTimeBroker;
        }

        protected IDateTimeBroker DateTimeBroker { get; }

        protected override Task HandleRequirementAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context, MinimumAgeRequirement requirement)
        {

            if (!context.User.HasClaim(c => c.Type == JwtClaimTypes.BirthDate))
            {
                return Task.CompletedTask;
            }
            var claimValue = context.User.FindFirst(c => c.Type == JwtClaimTypes.BirthDate).Value;
            var dob = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<DateTimeOffset?>(claimValue);
            if (!dob.HasValue)
            {
                return Task.CompletedTask;
            }

            var dateOfBirth = dob.Value;


            int calculatedAge = DateTimeBroker.GetDateTime().Date.Year - dateOfBirth.Year;

            if (dateOfBirth > DateTimeBroker.GetDateTime().AddYears(-calculatedAge))
            {
                calculatedAge--;
            }

            if (calculatedAge >= requirement.MinimumAge)
            {
                context.Succeed(requirement);
            }

            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
    }
```

Comment: If this does not work for you I can make a repo I am working on public with policy and role based access on both the client and api.

Comment: Here is a working Repo : https://github.com/BrianLParker/AuthApp